# What changes are required to be made to ant classpath to enable non root users build java applications?

Tags: java, ant, wsdl, axis

We had a build setup with only a root user on CentOS. Ant command was running fine until we created some users. Now these users are not able to run ant command. Users see following error message

```
axis:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource axis-tasks.properties. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED

/home/akshay/code_17sp1/vobs/company/ipnpm_src/Pwg/build.xml:100: Problem: failed to create task or type axis-wsdl2java
    Cause: The name is undefined.
    Action: Check the spelling.
    Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
    Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

And build.xml:100

```
<axis-wsdl2java url="${company-pwg.base}/src/NpViewService.wsdl"
            output="${axis.output}">
```

I figure it has something to do with classpath OR permissions.

EDIT:

Classpaths:

```
export MSPSDK=8.10.0.3
export SONA_WSDL_VERSION=12.5.0.1
export TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp
export RELEASE=$HOME/Release
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/current
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/apache-ant-1.6.5
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

for root $HOME = /root
for user akshay $HOME = /home/akshay

Comment: yes it seems like a classpath issue. You need `axis-ant.jar` in ur classpath to use that task. Can u plz post your full CLASSPATH - for root and for another user?

Comment: @Pat Edited the question to add CLASSPATH. Can u plz verify that these are correct?

Comment: these are just your environment vars. where is ur classpath? Or you meant that all these paths are `ADDED` to your `CLASSPATH` variable? Also, verify whether ur user has access to `axis-ant.jar` file.

Comment: @Pat 1. The $CLASSPATH variable is not set for root or any other user. The output for "echo $CLASSPATH" is empty.
2. User has read permissions to access axis-ant.jar

Comment: @Pat What should be the values of $CLASSPATH variable for root and other users?

Comment: ur classpath may be set from ant's build.xml. check the values in classpath and check the link that Mark has mentioned in his answer below. This is most certainly a classpath issue. You need to analyze ur classpath entries more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The axis ANT task jar and dependencies are missing from the classpath. I'm guessing that the root user has some extra jars located it's home directory?

- /root/.ant/lib

For a generic solution that works for all users checkout the following answer:

- [ant command showing error while execution : resource axis-tasks.properties could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058098/ant-command-showing-error-while-execution-resource-axis-tasks-properties-could/25070193#25070193)

It uses the Apache [ivy plugin](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage dependencies.